# Can I connect a Nexus 4 to 1080p hdmi screen (@1080p) with the phone screen off?

Tags: nexus-4, hdmi, slimport

I am interested in using a SlimPort adapter to connect my Nexus 4 to an external monitor. I'm exploring the idea of using an Android device as a simple workstation with an external screen, keyboard & mouse.

1. Can Android run external HDMI monitors at a resolution other than the
   native resolution of the Android Device? As I understand it, the
   default behavior is to show the scale the native resolutions on the
   external monitor, but I'd like to output 1080p rather than the N4 native res.
2. Can I disable mirroring and use the HDMI device only? I’d like to
   run it with the screen off on the N4. This should reduce
   power consumption a bit and reduce to graphics workload. Is there something similar to linux's xrandr on Android that would allows
   this?
3. Could I user Tasker or anything else to accomplish this automatically when the SlimPort adapter is plugged in?

Nexus 4 running rooted 4.4